# How to move message to Trash in gmail imap?

Tags: ios4, gmail, imap, imaplib

I am creating an application in which I need to delete mail using IMAP in gmail. But when I set the flag to delete the message moves to spam folder instead of trash or directly deletion. Is there any way to move message to trash?

**UPDATE**

Now my messages are moving from inbox to important folder. I'm sending message to my self( in web browser) and it's marked as important by default.

Answer (score 0):

There is a Google [support site](https://mail.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?answer=78892) that says "Do NOT save deleted messages to your [Gmail]/Trash folder because this will delete a message in all folders." - so you might want to do exactly that :)

Answer (score 0):

Adding onto flob's answer

the following folder paths works too

it seems like it's depending on when the user sign up for gmail

"[Gmail]/Trash"

"[Google Mail]/Bin"

"[Gmail]/Bin"